# Where is my logic wrong?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

I want to ask the question 4 times, and alert if they user is under, over, close, or right and break loop. Where is my logic off? Recognizes everything but the last else if?

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  var myNumber = prompt('guess my number?');
  if(myNumber > 50) {
    alert('to high');
  }else if(myNumber <= 8) {
    alert('too low');
  }else if(myNumber > 8 && myNumber < 20) {
    alert('youre getting closer');
  }else if (myNumber === 12) {
    alert('yay');
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

First, you have (before the question was edited):

```
}else if(myNumber < 8 && myNumber > 20) {
```

Correct is:

```
}else if(myNumber > 8 && myNumber < 20 ) {
```

(I inverted `<` and `>`)

In fact you want to check if the `myNumber` is **between** 9 and 19.

Note that your original statement would always be evaluated **false**.

---

Then you have to check the correct number "12" **before** you check if the user is "getting closer".

The whole thing becomes:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  var myNumber = prompt('guess my number?');
  if (myNumber === 12) { // <-- let's check the right number first
    alert('yay');
    break;
  } else if(myNumber > 50) {
    alert('to high');
  }else if(myNumber < 3) {
    alert('too low');
  }else if(myNumber > 8 && myNumber < 20) { // <-- fixed here
    alert('youre getting closer');
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed a few other things